# Need help in Merging Two query for HP ALM

Tags: mysql, sql, alm

I have two different query in HP ALM, but i want to merge and get it into one. I am not that good in SQL query so I am facing hard time in merging the query.

Query 1: Getting the execution Count for the tester

```
Select
 TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER as 'Tester',
 sum(case when TC_Status In('Blocked','Passed','Failed','Not Completed') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total',
 sum(case when TC_Status = 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Pass',
 sum(case when TC_Status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Fail',
 sum(case when TC_Status = 'Blocked' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Blocked',
 sum(case when TC_Status In('Not Completed','Defferred','N/A') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Others'

From  TESTCYCL
Where
 TESTCYCL.TC_EXEC_DATE = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
 And
 TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER in ('Username1')
 Group by TC_ACTUAL_TESTER
```

Query 2: Getting the Defect raise by the tester

```
SELECT
 BG_DETECTED_BY,
 Sum(case when BG_Status Not in ('Closed','Defect Resolved','Rejected')then 1 else 0 end) as 'Defect Raised'
 FROM BUG
 Where BUG.BG_DETECTED_BY in ('username1')
 AND BUG.BG_DETECTION_DATE = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
 Group by BG_DETECTED_BY
```

I have tried inner join/ Left Join but the count of the defect raised by the user is not matching

Query3 : That i have tried:

```
 Select
  TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER as 'Tester',
  sum(case when TC_Status In('Blocked','Passed','Failed','Not Completed') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total',
  sum(case when TC_Status = 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Pass',
  sum(case when TC_Status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Fail',
  sum(case when TC_Status = 'Blocked' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Blocked',
  sum(case when TC_Status In('Not Completed','Defferred','N/A') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Others',
  Sum(case when BG_Status Not in ('Closed','Defect Resolved','Rejected')then 1 else 0 end) as 'Defect Raised'

From  TESTCYCL 
Left Join BUG 
  on TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER =  BUG.BG_DETECTED_BY 
 AND  BUG.BG_DETECTION_DATE = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
Where TESTCYCL.TC_EXEC_DATE = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
  And TESTCYCL.TC_ACTUAL_TESTER in ('username1')
Group by TC_ACTUAL_TESTER
```

Out is mentioned as below:

```
Expected Output:
Tester   Total Execution  Passed  Failed  ... Defect Raised
  A          5              3       2             10

Actual Output:
Tester   Total Execution  Passed  Failed  ... Defect Raised
  A          56              3       2             45
```

Comment: we need sample data and result fo each query. so we can try to reach your expected output. Otherwise we dont know where to start

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for the prompt reply, but the table schema is too big to provide. All i can say if someone has worked on the HP ALM then they will have a better understanding.  Please see the schema TESTCYCL and BUG [Tables_Schema](http://systemmanager.ru/322224.en/)

Comment: I understand but you try to create a MVC so we can understand it and test. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise we have to spend a lot of time trying to decipher what you have.

Comment: Also can't be too big. Tester A has 5+3+2+10 rows. you can provide that data.

Comment: do you expect have more than one username? Otherwise you should use `TC_ACTUAL_TESTER = 'username1'`

Comment: Yes, there is more user, due to the restriction i might not be able to share.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are doing the `COUNT()` over the product cartesian. instead of concatenating the result.

Right now you are doing

```
   COUNT(A*B) instead of COUNT(A) || COUNT(B)
```

general example, if you have two queries

```
SELECT * FROM A (ex: 10 rows)
SELECT * FROM B (ex: 10 rows)
```

What you need is:

```
 SELECT temp1.*, temp2.*
 FROM (SELECT * FROM A) as temp1
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM B) as temp2
   ON temp1.ID = temp2.ID
```

Comment: Wish you can create some mock data instead some generic question. While here is a generic answer

Comment: I will try ur above example. and will try to create a pseudo data with the table. Please bear with me for a while. Thanks

Comment: temp1.*.. Is it .* or something else

Comment: temp1 is the alias for the first subquery. So temp1.* are all the fields from that subquery. What is the question?

Comment: Getting Invalid coloumn name on `ON Temp1.ID = Temp2.ID`

Comment: `ID` is a generic field . In your case is `TC_ACTUAL_TESTER`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159163/discussion-between-nishit-dey-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: Sorry,  I dont think this question deserve much more of my time